# How to change directory under git bash

Tags: windows, git, bash, command-line

Could you tell me please how to change directory using git bash?

Exactly I want go to `C:/Program Files`

I type `cd c:/`    - move to `c:/`.

I type `cd Program Files` and I get message that "there is no such directory Program".

So the problem is how to go to the directory name of which consists of two words that are separated by whitespaces.

I'm using Windows 7 operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cd` gets just one argument, so if you say `cd Program Files` it does `cd Program`. So you need to quote `Program Files` if you want `cd` to it as just one argument:

```
cd "Program Files"
```

otherwise it is trying to find the directory `Program`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also type the space as escape seqence:

```
cd /c/Program\ Files/Git/
```

Answer (score -1):

Please find below to add windows path in git bash or in unix

```
export PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_221/bin:/c/Program\ Files/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin
```